# Apply ufunc to xarray single Dataset variable as delayed operation using dask

Tags: python, dask, python-xarray

I would like to apply a custom function to a variable within an `xarray.Dataset` modifying only the specified variable. At the same time I am trying to make this part of a `dask` computation graph so it can be delayed prior to reading out to disk with `to_netcdf`.

At the moment I can apply the `ufunc` using `xr.apply_ufunc()` but only to all variables within the Dataset.

I understand I could probably access the variable directly using it's name like `Dataset.var` and pass this to `apply_ufunc()` but I don't quite understand how the output of this function (a delayed future) would be recombined with the original dataset prior to output.

Ideally, I want to do **something like** this (where `'data.nc'` has multiple variables and only `var1` is squared).

```
import xarray as xr
from distributed import Client

dask_client = Client()

def square(x):
    return x*x

data = xr.open_dataset('data.nc', chunks={'d1':10})
fut_sq = xr.apply_ufunc(square, data.var1, dask='parallelized', output_dtypes=['float'])
data.var1 = fut_sq.var1
fut_save = data.to_netcft('new.nc', compute=False)

dask_client.compute(fut_save)
```

Answer (score 0):

So I played around with this a bit more and decided that the best way to do this was to extract the data from the netCDF4 file, convert it to a `dask.array` and then rewrite a new file to disk. This involves writing custom functions using the `dask.delayed` functionality. Using the `ufunc` approach was probably inappropriate for my problem.

A few drawbacks of this:

1. You don't seem to be able to modify the file in place. To save the modified variables from the original NetCDF4 file you have to rewrite the whole file to disk.
2. For me at least, the best way to parallelise the custom `square` function was to create my own data chunks and pass these to chunks individually to `square`. Then reconstitute them using `dask.array.concatenate`. I know `dask` has some bagging functionality but I struggled to get it to work the way I wanted.
3. The reading of the file happens in parallel but it does not appear that `dask` writes to NetCDF4 in parallel.

It would be great if I can be corrected on these points.

Here is my amended example

```
import xarray as xr
from distributed import Client
import dask
import dask.array as da

dask_client = Client()

def bag_slices(ind, n=10):
    bag = list()
    prev = 0
    for i in range(len(ind)):
        if (i+1)%n == 0:
            bag.append(slice(prev, i+1, 1))
            prev = i+1
    if prev != i+1:
        bag.append(slice(prev, i+1, 1))
    return bag

@dask.delayed
def square(x):
    return x*x

@dask.delayed
def assign(old_xr_dataset, new_data):
    old_xr_dataset['var1'].values = new_data
    return old_xr_dataset

# for me data.data.var1 is 3D and I process by splitting the data along the second dimension.
with xr.open_dataset('data.nc', chunks={'d1':10}) as data:
    # create slice bags for distributed processing along preferred axis
    bags = bag_slices(data.coords['dim2'].values, n=10)
    # convert to dask array
    data_da = da.from_array(data.var1.values)
    # create data bags
    bags = [data_da[:, slc, :] for slc in bags]

    future_squared = []
    for data_bag in bags:
        # concatenate doesn't understand delayed objects 
        # so must convert them back to delayed arrays
        future_squared.append(da.from_delayed(square(data_bag), data_bag.shape, dtype=float))
    data_new = dask.array.concatenate(future_squared, axis=1)

    fut_dataset = assign(data, data_new)
    fut_nc_save = fut_dataset.to_netcdf('data_squared.nc', compute=False)
    fut_nc_save.compute()
```